# HammerJS - Limit function call rate inside drag event

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm using the drag event with HammerJS for changing the value of a input range.

If I change the value of the input range on each drag event the HammerJS keeps firing it so fast that some mobile devices crash.

How can I limit the function call rate inside drag event?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can change the rate of events called, because the events trigger, when something on the screen changes (e.g. a finger slides from a position to another). But you could perhaps try to limit the handling of the event.

Something like this could do the job:

```
var lastDeltaX, lastDeltaY = 0;

hammer.on("pan", function(event) {

    if((lastDetaX - event.deltaX) < 5 ||
       (lastDetaY - event.deltaY) < 5)
    {

        //Do something

        lastDeltaX = event.deltaX;
        lastDeltaY = event.deltaY;
    }
});
```

Comment: Typo in if statement variable names by the way

Comment: Also, `event.deltaX` is undefined in mousemove listeners

Answer (score 0):

Rate limit based on time and not movement:

```js
let lastDrag = 0;

let onMouseMove = function (e) {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (now - lastDrag < 10) {
    return;
  }

  lastDrag = now;

  // your code
};

myElement.addEventListener("mousemove", onMouseMove);
```

This will work in vanilla JS too